# RegEx expression to avoid spam with symbols

Tags: regex

I need a RegEx expression to avoid spam with symbols. I give you an example that I want to avoid with RegEx:

The normal IP:

```
5.196.39.29
```

The IP that I want to censore:

```
5.--.196.--.39.--.29
5  -  196  - 39  - 29
```

and all other combinations..

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what you are looking for:

```
5[\s.-]*196[\s.-]*39[\s.-]*29
```

Will detect all the following cases:

```
5.196.39.29
5.--.196.--.39.--.29
5  -  196  - 39  - 29
```

You can check it here: https://www.regex101.com/r/kP9mI2/1

Comment: Thanks a lot! It worked! I'm going to check it as the right question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like what you want is "5, some non-digits, 196, some non-digits, 39, some non-digits, 29"

That looks like this:

```
/5\D+196\D+39\D+29/
```